Adjusting p values for FDR for selected features
I am trying to associate the expression of certain genes of interest from Bulk RNA and scRNA sequencing experiments done in a large cohort with clinical outcomes. Do I need to adjust for FDR in this case, given that I am only testing a few number of genes ≈ 5.
Thanks

Have you searched for previous questions relevant to yours? You will find a lot of relevant discussion using search terms "FDR" and "multiple comparisons correction".

It is not possible to answer this question without you telling us your research context. Is this a preliminary study? What will you do with the results?

Apologies for ambiguity. The study is not preliminary. The study is about certain genes, we hypothesis that are related to the outcome, where we tested on animal models. We wanted to confirm this in human, and so we utilised data from large cohort that has been done by others, to look at the association with the outcome i.e hospitalisations and mortality. In most of cases I apply FDR correction when testing all genes that has been analysed by the platform. However, as we are interested only in few of them, would FDR correction be necessary? I hope I clarified my question.

Please add this new information as an edit to the post, not only as a comment. Comments on this site are ephemeral, and often seen only by a few
